# Accessing a button in a callback (Gmail Addon)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have a button that should disappear upon clicking.

```
CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('submitForm');
var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Yes')
.setOnClickAction(submitForm);
```

In submitForm() I want to hide/remove the button, How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Either pop the card (removing the "form" and button), or just reset the form card for a new submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the submitForm action callback, create a navigation with updateCard for the same card by passing a flag to hide the button. Follow the code below:

```
function getCard(hideBtn) {
var cb = CardService.newCardBuilder();

cb.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card Header"));

var section = CardService.newCardSection();

if(!hideBtn) {
    var submitForm = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('submitForm');
    var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Yes').setOnClickAction(submitForm);
    section.addWidget(submitButton);
}

cb.addSection(section);

return cb.build();
}

function submitForm(e) {
   var navigation = CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(getCard(true));
   return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(navigation).build();
```

}